# keeping a traversal count in prolog

Tags: prolog, maze

I have a program I've written in Prolog that deals with the classic rat in a maze example, but I'm trying to add to it a bit of functionality. Basically, I want to keep a count of how many rooms have been traversed so far, and ensure that a certain condition has been met at least once in the past three traversals (rooms in the maze).

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
connected(X,Y):-
   d(X,Y);d(Y,X).

path(A,B,Path):-
   go(A,B,[A],Q),
   reverse(Q,Path).

go(A,B,P,[B|P]):-
   connected(A,B).
go(A,B,Visited,Path):-
   connected(A,C), C\==B,
   not(member(C,Visited)),
   go(C,B,[C|Visited],Path).

cheese(X):-
   cheese(X).
```

I realize I probably don't need the last predicate since I could just directly say cheese(c), cheese(b), etc, but it's mostly there to remind myself of where I'm going with this and to actually write the check for cheese into the traversal.

The main issue I'm having here is that I'm unsure how to have the counter increment/decrement appropriately on traversal or backtracking. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**
I attempted to modify my predicates to keep a Hunger counter and increment or return to seed if cheese(X) with cheese(_). as a fact in the code, but testing it with previously established paths causes the program to continually return false.

code:

```
connected(X,Y):-
    d(X,Y);d(Y,X).

go(A,B,P,[B|P], H):-
    H < 3, connected(A,B).

go(A,B,Visited,Path, H, H1):-
    connected(A,C), C\==B,
    not(member(C,Visited)),
    ( cheese(A) ->  H is H1 %consume
        ;   H is H1+1), %starve
    go(C,B,[C|Visited],Path, H).


path(A,B,Path,H):- %H for hunger count.
    go(A,B,[A],Q, H, 0), %0 hunger seed.
    reverse(Q,Path).

d(enter,b).
d(b,c).
d(b,e).
d(d,e).
d(c,d).
d(e,f).
d(e,exit).

cheese(_).
```

query: `path(enter,exit,Path,H).`

Comment: You need to add an a couple of arguments to your predicate for the `Count` and update it as needed. You'll need an initial count (starts at 0) and an updated count.

Comment: You have a list of visited node, simply take it's length when you find a succesive branch.

Comment: updating the predicate to include the count makes sense, and I figured it'd be something like that; I'm just trying to wrap my head around how i'd go about updating it.

Also, taking the length was something I'd though about, but wouldn't that not work in many cases (where length(visited) > 3?) I want it to check for each increment of 3 not just within a total number of moves.

Comment: @Xellarant: The simplest way is to use [tag:clpfd] constraints.